# Matter js Body.set not updating objects position

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have a [Matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) World where I'm updating some [Bodies](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_set).

```
let ball1 = document.getElementById("ball-1");
let ball2 = document.getElementById("ball-2");
let ball3 = document.getElementById("ball-3");


// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Events = Matter.Events;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

// create 3 circles and walls
var circle1 = Bodies.circle(w/2, 40, ball1.offsetWidth/2, { restitution: 0.99 });
var circle2 = Bodies.circle(w/2, 100, ball2.offsetWidth/2, { restitution: 0.99 });
var circle3 = Bodies.circle(w/2, 50, ball3.offsetWidth/2, { restitution: 0.99 });

var ceiling = Bodies.rectangle(w/2, -15, w, 30, { isStatic: true });
var wallLeft = Bodies.rectangle(-15, h/2, 30, h, { isStatic: true, restitution: 0.99 });
var wallRight = Bodies.rectangle(w+15, h/2, 30, h, { isStatic: true, restitution: 0.99 });
var floor = Bodies.rectangle(w/2, h+15, w, 30, { isStatic: true, restitution: 0.99 });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [circle1, circle2, circle3, floor, wallLeft, wallRight, ceiling]);
Engine.run(engine);

Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", function(){
  ball1.style.transform = "translateX(" + circle1.position.x + "px) translateY(" + circle1.position.y + "px) rotate("+circle1.angle+"rad)";
  ball2.style.transform = "translateX(" + circle2.position.x + "px) translateY(" + circle2.position.y + "px)  rotate("+circle2.angle+"rad)";
  ball3.style.transform = "translateX(" + circle3.position.x + "px) translateY(" + circle3.position.y + "px)  rotate("+circle3.angle+"rad)";
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when I'm resizing the window, I'm calling the following method:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;

  Body.set(circle1, { x: w/2, y: 10 });
  Body.set(circle2, { x: w/2 + 10, y: 10 });
  Body.set(circle3, { x: w/2 - 10, y: 10 });
  Body.set(floor, { x: w/2, width: w, y: h+15 });
  Body.set(ceiling, { x: w/2, width: w });
  Body.set(wallLeft, { y: h/2, height: h });
  Body.set(wallRight, { x: w+15, y: h/2, height: h });
  console.log(floor.y);
});
```

But, while the `console.log` is showing the new `y` position of the floor, the elements on screen aren't updating. Am I calling this function wrong?

```
Body.set(floor, { x: w/2, width: w, y: h+15 });
```

Full demo:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/9fe08dd4365f63666be2e53a676642c7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but if anyone has the same question, I'd better answer this.

In matter-js

update position using

```
Matter.Body.set(circle1, "position", {x: 100, y: 100})
```

Source code link : https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/e909b0466cea2051267bab92a38ccaa9bf7f154e/src/body/Body.js#L222

Comment: There's also `Matter.Body.setPosition(body, {x, y})`

Comment: For anyone coming from Phaser >= 3.60, you can use `scene.matter.body.setPosition(circle1, new Phaser.Math.Vector2(100, 100), false)`